# I have a onchange that don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
    $(function() {
        $(".controlgroup").controlgroup();
        $(".controlgroup-vertical").controlgroup({
            "direction" : "vertical"
        });
        $("#banche").on("change", function() {
            alert("prova");
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="primo" class="controlgroup">
<select id="banche">
            <option></option>
            <?php 
                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
                {
                    $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","sist.bancario") or die("Errore durante la connessione");
                    $sql="select * from banche";
                    $rs=$con->query($sql) or die("Errore nella sintassi della query");
                    for($i=0;$i<$rs->num_rows;$i++)
                    {
                            $resrow= mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
                            echo "<option value=".$resrow[1].">$resrow[1]</option>";
                    }
                    $con->close();
                }
            ?>
</select>
```

the function change doesn't work and i don't know why please help me
i have tried a lot of alternative, but they don't work too

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. "Why doesn't this code work?" is not a valid type of question here. please spend a little more time forming your question and explaining what you have tried...

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/controlgroup/ results in the select being a http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ which of course has it's own special change event.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event listener to body like this:

```
 $(body).on("change", "#banche", function(){
      alert("prova");
 });
```

Comment: Maybe explain to the user why you are suggesting them to use a delegated event binding?  And what exactly that is, in case they don't know.